# STRING_SPLIT in TSQL on MS Server creates list with repeating values. WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using 2017 MS SQL Express. The following code creates this erroneous result. Any clues why?

```
SELECT BNAME, LIC_STRING INTO dbo.SEPARATE2
FROM dbo.together
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(LIC_STRING, ',');  


table dbo.together                         result, dbo.SEPARATE2

BNAME | LIC_STRING                         BNAME | LIC_STRING

A1    | AB,AC,AD                             A1  | AB,AC,AD
B2    | AX,AD                                A1  | AB,AC,AD
                                             A1  | AB,AC,AD
                                             B2  | AX,AD
                                             B2  | AX,AD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `cross apply` which is applying your join on 2 tables where result contain table on left with all the columns and table on right with matching values.

Since in this query `dbo.together` has 2 rows and for each value in `string_split` it generate same number of rows. `1:n` relation in between these 2 tables.

```
SELECT TOGETHER.BNAME, STR.VALUE INTO dbo.SEPARATE2
FROM dbo.together AS TOGETHER
CROSS APPLY (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(TOGETHER.LIC_STRING, ',')) AS STR;
```

You may find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more details on `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are selecting the *original* values.  Your query multiplies the number of values -- one for each element, but you are not selecting those values.

You probably want each element, so include that in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT t.BNAME, s.value
INTO dbo.SEPARATE2
FROM dbo.together t CROSS APPLY 
     STRING_SPLIT(t.LIC_STRING, ',') s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24a70206df67adba966f52bd0344d1cc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I see. Thank you, but it gives me `"'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized function name"` error.

Comment: @Kokokoko - use `SELECT t.BNAME, value as element
INTO dbo.SEPARATE2
FROM dbo.together t CROSS APPLY 
     STRING_SPLIT(t.LIC_STRING, ',')`